# Swagger context-based size constraints

Tags: java, swagger, springdoc

We use springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.1 in the project. Some "child" DTOs are common and used in different top-level request-response "parent" DTOs. Is there a way to specify different length constraints on, for example, String properties of such shared "child" DTOs, basing on in which top-level DTOs it is nested via composition? I.e.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Request {
    private NameContainter holder;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Response {
    private NameContainter holder;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class NameContainer {
   private String name;
}
```

In Request **holder.name** maximum length must be up to 20 characters, in Response - up to 50.
As far as I digged into *swagger-core-2.1.2.jar:io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.ModelResolver*, it has VERY straightforward logic of working with property constraints - if it sees JSR-303 Bean Validation annotations, values from them are simply put into a corresponding Schema object without any "path-dependent" analysis of where property is used.

Comment: Do you mean to say, reuse the same POJO but apply a different set of constraints?

Comment: Yes you're right